# How to pad feature maps before max pool?

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to code an autoencoder which takes tensor of shape (None,194, 434, 626, 3). Problem is after maxpool the dimensions become odd and next maxpool rounds them off. While decoding using upsample, I can't get the output dimension to be same as input dimension. I thought padding befor maxpooling might help, but tf.pad isn't affecting the tensors.

```
x = Activation('relu')(x)
print(x.shape)
tf.pad(x, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,0]], "CONSTANT")
print(x.shape)
encoded = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(x)
print(x.shape)
```

> (?, 97, 217, 313, 8)
>
> (?, 97, 217, 313, 8)
>
> (?, 49, 109, 157, 8)

What am I doing wrong? What are the best methods for upsampling in decoding?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.pad` doesn't work in place. You need to assign the result.

`x = tf.pad(x, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,0]], "CONSTANT")`

Comment: that gives `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'`

Comment: I am instead now using the keras layer zero padding. not sure why tensorflow one isn't working